# SocketException when initiating a webRequest in c#

Tags: c#, security, sockets, httpwebrequest

i am having a internet / security issue with some code i have written.

Basically i am trying to initiate a HttpWebRequest from c# code to a particular URL. nothing fancy, just a basic request.

When i execute on my local machine it works fine.

When i deploy the code to a Windows server 2003 environment the GetResponse method exceptions as follows...

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx()
```

Interestingly, if i put the same URL into an internet explorer browser, the page loads fine so i dont think its a connectivity issue.

I have thought maybe firewall? -> but its turned off.

I also investigation .NET runtime security and temporarily set the All_Code group to have FullTrust.

Lastly, i added the URL to the trusted sites group.

No idea!!

Can anyone help?

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postURL);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpRequest.GetResponse();
```

Here is the trace log...

> System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   WebRequest::Create(http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
>   System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   HttpWebRequest#63835064::HttpWebRequest(http://xxxxxxxxxx#-1903155940)
>   System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5004] Exiting
>   HttpWebRequest#63835064::HttpWebRequest()
>   System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5004] Exiting
>   WebRequest::Create()  ->
>   HttpWebRequest#63835064 System.Net
>   Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   HttpWebRequest#63835064::GetResponse()
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [5004]
>   Associating HttpWebRequest#63835064
>   with ServicePoint#11454272 System.Net
>   Information: 0 : [5004] Associating
>   Connection#60504909 with
>   HttpWebRequest#63835064
>   System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Socket#21950498::Socket(InterNetwork#2)
>   System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Exiting Socket#21950498::Socket() 
>   System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Socket#21950498::Connect(53:80#904160388)
>   System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Exiting Socket#21950498::Connect() 
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [5004]
>   Associating HttpWebRequest#63835064
>   with ConnectStream#37614147 System.Net
>   Information: 0 : [5004]
>   HttpWebRequest#63835064 - Request:
>   POST /xxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1
>
> System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Socket#21950498::Send()
>   System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Data from Socket#21950498::Send
>
> // SOCKET DATA
>
> System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Exiting Socket#21950498::Send()   ->
>   297#297 System.Net Information: 0 :
>   [5004] ConnectStream#37614147 -
>   Sending headers { Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Host: paint.pure360.com Connection:
>   Keep-Alive }. System.Net.Sockets
>   Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Socket#21950498::Receive()
>   System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Data from Socket#21950498::Receive
>
> // SOCKET DATA
>
> System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Exiting Socket#21950498::Receive()    ->
>   176#176 System.Net Information: 0 :
>   [5004] Connection#60504909 - Received
>   status line: Version=1.1,
>   StatusCode=302,
>   StatusDescription=Found. System.Net
>   Information: 0 : [5004]
>   Connection#60504909 - Received headers
>   { Connection: close Content-Length: 0
>   Content-Type: text/html Date: Wed, 23
>   Mar 2011 00:59:11 GMT Location:
>   http://xxxxxxxxx Server: Apache }.
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [5004]
>   ConnectStream#35460724::ConnectStream(Buffered
>   0 bytes.) System.Net.Sockets Verbose:
>   0 : [5004] Socket#21950498::Dispose()
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [5004]
>   Associating HttpWebRequest#63835064
>   with ConnectStream#35460724 System.Net
>   Information: 0 : [5004] Associating
>   HttpWebRequest#63835064 with
>   HttpWebResponse#65961401 System.Net
>   Warning: 0 : [5004]
>   HttpWebRequest#63835064::() - Error
>   code 302 was received from server
>   response. System.Net Warning: 0 :
>   [5004] HttpWebRequest#63835064::() -
>   Resubmitting request. System.Net
>   Information: 0 : [5004] Associating
>   HttpWebRequest#63835064 with
>   ServicePoint#47602007 System.Net
>   Information: 0 : [5004] Associating
>   Connection#3927761 with
>   HttpWebRequest#63835064
>   System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Socket#66771947::Socket(InterNetwork#2)
>   System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Exiting Socket#66771947::Socket() 
>   System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Socket#66771947::Connect(22:80#383746063)
>   System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [5004]
>   Exception in the
>   Socket#66771947::Connect - A
>   connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond
>   95.128.223.22:80 System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [5004]
>   Socket#66771947::Dispose() System.Net
>   Error: 0 : [5004] Exception in the
>   HttpWebRequest#63835064:: - Unable to
>   connect to the remote server
>   System.Net Error: 0 : [5004]    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream
>   PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean
>   async, IPAddress& address, Socket&
>   abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6,
>   Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object
>   owningObject, Boolean async, Int32
>   timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate
>   asyncCallback)    at
>   System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(Boolean
>   async, HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
>   System.Net Error: 0 : [5004] Exception
>   in the
>   HttpWebRequest#63835064::EndGetResponse
>   - Unable to connect to the remote server System.Net Error: 0 : [5004]
>   at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream
>   PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean
>   async, IPAddress& address, Socket&
>   abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6,
>   Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object
>   owningObject, Boolean async, Int32
>   timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate
>   asyncCallback)    at
>   System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(Boolean
>   async, HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)

Comment: Can you browse to the url in IE from the Windows 2003 environment?

Comment: @tdaines yes as i mentioned above. IE shows the page fine with no warnings or issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Win2003 configuration probably has a default proxy that is causing this problem. Go into InternetOptions of your IE installation and see if there is a proxy being used. Also, giveing a snippet of the code will help understand the issue more.

Comment: hi @feroze, have checked for the existance of a proxy and there is none. further, this is a winforms application -> isnt a trace log for an asp.net application?

Comment: The config file should work for any application. Just rename it to app.exe.config where app.exe is your executable filename.

Comment: hi @feroze i have attached the trace information. does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on you server you're trying to access.

Try supplying a user agent:

```
httpRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)";
```

Comment: hmmm. but as i said, the code runs fine on my local.. would that mean that the user agent is irrelevant?